# Error Writing/Reading Latch with Silicon Labs CP210X USB to UART Bridge (Driver Version 6.0.0.0)

Tags: c#, serial-port, uart

We have installed **Silicon Labs CP210X USB to UART Bridge (Driver Version 6.0.0.0)**  driver in the system working in Windows 10 64 bit, for some reasons we don't want to use the latest driver(10.1.3.2130).

Now we try read and write to the GPIO pins using CP210x Port Read/Write example  but we are getting Write and Read errors with Silicon Labs CP210X USB to UART Bridge (Driver Version 6.0.0.0).

Can we able to Read and Write without using the latest CP210X USB to UART Bridge Driver?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the CP2102N you are using on an evaluation kit (EVK), a custom PCB, or a commercial product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Silicon Labs employee.

I'm not sure why you are using version 6.0.0.0 of the driver.  Version 6.0.0.0 of the VCP driver predates the CP2102N, so that may be the issue.  Even if you do not want to use the Windows 10 only driver, the latest 7/8/8.1 driver is 6.7.6.  See this page for more information: https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers